# Failed to fetch sudo apt-get update

Tags: updates

When I want to update:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/osd-lyrics/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/osd-lyrics/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any idea?

Comment: The PPA repository no longer exist.

Comment: so i need to create a repository??

how to?

Comment: You can not create a repository `just like that`. This means you will not get any updates from this repository any more